# TestCafe Triggered "Assertion Error" while Assertion was Correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, testcafe, end-to-end

I am currently using `Testcafe` for `en-to-end` testing, and I needed to assert if a text is correctly displayed. the code is written as shown below:

```js
 await t
    .expect(Selector('div:nth-child(5) > div > table:nth-child(3) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)  
        td:nth-child(1)').filterVisible().innerText).contains('FOR LEASE')
    .expect(Selector('div:nth-child(5) > div > table:nth-child(5) > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > 
        td:nth-child(1)').filterVisible().innerText).contains('200 Granville Street')
```

but to my surprise, I got the error below on the console:

[console error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIL4M.png)

```js
DEBUGGER PAUSE ON FAILED TEST:
AssertionError: expected 'FOR LEASE' to include 'FOR LEASE'
```

From the console error, the text on the element was the same as my assertion. Hence I am confused as to why this is failing. kindly help with some suggestions.

> In addition, I first tried `.eql()` before reducing the strict equality by using `.contains()`. however, I got the same error on both.

Comment: Is there any [empty character](http://emptycharacter.com/) in one of these values? If not, please provide a simple example where we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Yes, there was a space in the string. which introduces the error when included in the assertion. but when I assert for "FOR" and "LEASE" it succeeds.

Answer (score 1):

After thoroughly debugging this issue, I discovered that

when the document is edited, the website `encodes` the `string` (while converting it to `PDF`) before saving. Hence, when I tried to assert the change after the text has been saved, It failed (although the words looked alike visually). This error was particularly due to the space encoding.

what got the job done was to assert sections of the string without spaces

> **Now the question is**:  In a future scenario like this, how can I normalize the encoded space before asserting, so I wouldn't always find an easy way out as I did above

Comment: It's better to ask additional questions separately.

Comment: The above is an answer, however, I knew it wasn't perfect. so the question at the tail end was just to show its imperfection for any other person to elaborate on ✌.

but your point is noted